# Converting List string or string to dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that captures information and I need to transform the output of this information into a data frame using pytesseract and cv2

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image, ImageEnhance
import time
from pytesseract import Output




size = 1000, 1000
chats = []
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd 
='My Patch to Tesseract'

def ScreenSearch():

 while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    img = (ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(1290, 247, 1586, 517)))
    img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Perform text extraction
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, lang='eng', config='--psm 
6')

    print(data)
    print(type(data))
    
    chats.append(data)
    print(chats)
    print(type(chats))
    
ScreenSearch()
```

the outputs are in this format resulting in

```
Preco(USDT) Quantia(BTC) Total
23624.21 0.00617 145.76138
23624.04 0.02000 472.48080
23624.00 0.00100 YRS tt)
23623.60 0.00650 153.55340
23623.37 0.00842 198.90878
23623.36 0.00846 199.85363
23623.28 0.00636 150.24406
23623.27 0.01913 451.91316
23623.01 0.00640 151.18726
23622.98 0.00675 159.45512
23622.85 0.00052 12.28388
23622.84 0.00210 49.60796

<class 'str'>
['Preco(USDT) Quantia(BTC) Total\n23624.21 0.00617 145.76138\n23624.04 0.02000 472.48080\n23624.00 0.00100 YRS tt)\n23623.60 0.00650 153.55340\n23623.37 0.00842 198.90878\n23623.36 0.00846 199.85363\n23623.28 0.00636 150.24406\n23623.27 0.01913 451.91316\n23623.01 0.00640 151.18726\n23622.98 0.00675 159.45512\n23622.85 0.00052 12.28388\n23622.84 0.00210 49.60796\n']
<class 'list'>
```

How to transform one or both outputs into data frame?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv` to convert the string to dataframe. You can use blank space as separator and add errors handle on lines with too much values (like `23624.00 0.00100 YRS tt)`).

*`sep=' '` can be replaced with `delim_whitespace=True` if you prefer

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' ', on_bad_lines=lambda x: x[:3], engine='python')
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Preco(USDT)  Quantia(BTC)      Total
0      23624.21       0.00617  145.76138
1      23624.04       0.02000  472.48080
2      23624.00       0.00100        YRS
3      23623.60       0.00650  153.55340
4      23623.37       0.00842  198.90878
5      23623.36       0.00846  199.85363
6      23623.28       0.00636  150.24406
7      23623.27       0.01913  451.91316
8      23623.01       0.00640  151.18726
9      23622.98       0.00675  159.45512
10     23622.85       0.00052   12.28388
11     23622.84       0.00210   49.60796
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.IO`:

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Preco(USDT) Quantia(BTC) Total
23624.21 0.00617 145.76138
23624.04 0.02000 472.48080
23624.00 0.00100 YRS
23623.60 0.00650 153.55340
23623.37 0.00842 198.90878
23623.36 0.00846 199.85363
23623.28 0.00636 150.24406
23623.27 0.01913 451.91316
23623.01 0.00640 151.18726
23622.98 0.00675 159.45512
23622.85 0.00052 12.28388
23622.84 0.00210 49.60796""".replace(' ', ','))

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Two things to note:
Since there is `YRS` instead of `YRS tt` in your desired output, I removed `tt` from the string. The second thing is you could directly use `string.IO` without needing `replace` but as your string has no seperator, I had to replace blanks with commas.